# Delete duplicate elements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to delete duplicate elements in SQL?
That is mean in each column, each element should only occur once.

For example, I have a table like:

```
NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 NAME4
A1    A2    A3    A4
A1    B2    A3    A4
A1    C2    C3    B4
B1    C2    B3    C4
C1    B2    A3    B4
```

There are so many duplicate elements in each column and they are placed randomly.

I should convert it to the table like below:

```
NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 NAME4
A1    A2    A3    A4
B1    B2    B3    B4
C1    C2    C3    C4
```

Comment: This is not really how SQL is works.  The *entity* in a table is the *row*.  You are mixing up values across all the rows.  If your processing is producing data like this, it is suspicious.

Comment: There are no duplicates in the example in your question

Comment: I mean remove the duplicate elements in each columns , so does this could not be solved by using SQL queries?

Comment: I am not clear how you get to the output you want. I can see that deduping name1 would result in a1,b1,c1 but I am not clear how you would pair these with a2,b2,c2 why would you not pair them with b2,a2,c2 , what should happen if name2 contained a1, what would happen if name2 only contained a2,c2.And I have the same diffiiculty with name3 and name4.

Comment: The order of a2,b2,c2 does not matter, I just want the non-duplicate names. If name2 contained a1, the second column should be A1, A2, B2,C2, and add nulls to other columns' 4th row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found out a solution to my problem.

Select the distinct names in each column as tables and then inner join them with adding common rownumbers could work.

However, this problem could be solved since the number of distinct names in each column are equal. I am still trying to find out how to solve the problem when the number of distinct names in each column are not equal.

```
set @r1 = 0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0;

select A.n1, B.n2, C.n3, D.n4 from

(select *,
case when n1 is not null then (@r1:=@r1+1) end as Rownumber
from(
select distinct NAME1 n1
from MYTABLE)Tn1)A

inner join

(select *,
case when n2 is not null then (@r2:=@r2+1) end as Rownumber
from(
select distinct NAME2 n2
from MYTABLE)Tn2)B

on A.Rownumber = B.Rownumber

inner join

(select *,
case when n3 is not null then (@r3:=@r3+1) end as Rownumber
from(
select distinct NAME3 n3
from MYTABLE)Tn3)C

on A.Rownumber = C.Rownumber

inner join

(select *,
case when n4 is not null then (@r4:=@r4+1) end as Rownumber
from(
select distinct NAME4 n4
from MYTABLE)Tn4)D

on A.Rownumber = D.Rownumber;
```

Comment: When the number of distinct names in each column are not equal, we can first use count(*) query to determine the column which has the largest number of distinct names, and then change 'inner join' to 'left join' or 'right join' corresponding to that column.